# Mongo Reference Schema Collections

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I’m looking to confirm that my collection structures will correctly allow for the reference I’m trying to make between my collections. Ideally I have a parent collection labeled category, where the child collection is labeled images. I plan on having around 4 documents for my “category” collection and 30 documents for my “images”. All of the documents were going to be uploaded from the command line with a csv file format. If I set up my schemas like I do below and upload the documents with headers matching the fields in the schemas, will I not have an issue with the reference points?

Category

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var categorySchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    description: String
});

var Category = mongoose.model(‘Category’, categorySchema);

module.exports = Category;
```

Images

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var imageSchema = new Schema({
    imageUrl: String,
    category_id: { type: sechema.ObjectId, ref:"categorySchema"}
});

var Images = mongoose.model('Images', imageSchema);

module.exports = Images;
```

Here is the layout of my .csv files

`category.csv`

```
**name**  **description**

Drama Stories about...
```

`images.csv`

```
**imageUrl**               **category_id**

www.site.com/image.jpg       Drama
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hopefully there can be only one `category` belonging to an `image`. One `category` having many `images` and each image `belongs` to only one `category`.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var categorySchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    description: String
    images: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Images'}]
});

var Category = mongoose.model(‘Category’, categorySchema);

module.exports = Category;

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var imageSchema = new Schema({
    imageUrl: String,
    category_id: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:"Category"}
});

var Images = mongoose.model('Images', imageSchema);

module.exports = Images;
```

**Note:** You would reference your `model` not `Schema`.

Then on you can use `mongoose` `middleware` to update your references while saving.

```
imageSchema.pre('save', function(next){
    var Category = require("../models/Category");
    var image = this;
    Category.findOneAndUpdate(
        {_id: {$in: {this.category_id}},
        {$push: {images: this._id}},
        next
    );
});
```

Comment: you are correct. Each image can only have one category associated with it. In regard to the middleware, I should place that `.pre` command right after I create the `imageSchema`, correct? Does it not really matter as long as its within the model file? Also, does this middleware basically listen for my .csv file upload and look for the values within the category_id for each image and make the adjustments to the data before being stored in the database?

Comment: Yes, you have to place right after imageSchema.. pre middleware would listen to Model.save() method...